# Where can I learn about advanced network programming, specifically for game development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming, multiplayer

I have currently been working on a multiplayer game using Node.js and Socket.io. I've done okay and I understand the basics, but the further I get into it, the more I realize I really don't understand how networking programming works. As the codebase grows and more features are added, my code is starting to become horribly inefficient and very hard to maintain.

The only resources I've really been able to find online cover very small applications and the methods used don't seem to have much scalability to them.

I'm wondering if anyone has a good book, or perhaps some online videos or articles that cover more advanced aspects or best practices of programming a large multiplayer game. I'm not new to game development, however I am new to the multiplayer and networking side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unix Network Programming, by Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) is the best I have seen on network programming. It is incredibly complete and thorough and clear. You can go as deep as you want to with this book.

Also check out the excellent [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) online.